# Change Listener not firing

Tags: java, multithreading, binding, javafx

I have a enum:

```
public enum TimelineState {
    PLAY,
    PAUSE, 
    STOPPED, 
    FINISHED 
}
```

And then I have a object property: `ObjectProperty<TimelineState>`

That object property is listened to by:

```
public class CallFinishedListener implements ChangeListener<TimelineState> {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TimelineState> arg0,
            TimelineState arg1, TimelineState arg2) {
            // do stuff
    }

}
```

I also have an invalidation listener:

```
state().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

            @Override
            public void invalidate() {
                         // do stuff
            }
});
```

When the following function changes the state, **ONLY the invalidation listener fires!** (why?)

```
@Override
public void pause() {
    this.setState(TimelineState.PAUSE);
}

@Override
public void reset() {
    this.movePlayheadTo(new TimeElapsed(0));
}

protected synchronized void finish() {
    // At this point, the value is TimelineState.FINISHED
    this.pause(); // This changes the state to TimelineState.PAUSE
    this.reset();
    state.set(TimelineState.FINISHED);
}
```

The only thing I can find is this blog post that vaguely mentions that change listeners only activate when the value "really changes"
http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/02/08/when-to-use-a-changelistener-or-an-invalidationlistener/

Comment: Have you considered adding a call to `notify()` or `notifyAll()`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No luck.

Comment: To what are you adding your Listener(s)?

Comment: the `ObjectProperty<TimelineState> state` property that I mentioned.

Comment: I see `state().addListener` - what is `state()`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `state()` is just the method to return the property for use outside the class. I managed to fix the problem though (see my answer). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem. The issue was that one of the change listeners in a completely different part of the program was `synchronized`. For some reason, that caused all other change listeners not to get the message, but leaving `InvalidationLister`s in the clear.

If anyone provides information on way this might be, I'm happy to accept that as an answer.